# How to find all null items in data table vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a data table with lot of items and some of the items are null.
I want to find all items with that are null and insert String.Empty.
Today it is done like that:

```
if IsDBNull(dtDiffFiles.Rows(0).Item("name"))
 dtDiffFiles.Rows(0).Item("name") = String.Empty
end if

if IsDBNull(dtDiffFiles.Rows(0).Item("address"))
 dtDiffFiles.Rows(0).Item("address") = String.Empty
end if
```

etc..

I want to do it in a way without writing the column (name, address)
Something like:

```
 if IsDBNull(dtDiffFiles.Rows(0).Item())
      dtDiffFiles.Rows(0).Item(col) = String.Empty
    End if
```

Is there any way to do it? (loop on all but without writing the col name)
I dont know if I have 10 or 100 cols, can I use count or somthing? (col.count?)
Thanks.

Comment: How are you Fill/Loading/Adding to the `dtDiffFiles`? If you're getting the data from a database you can replace nulls in your Command String: `SELECT ISNULL(ColName,'') AS ColName` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the rows and columns. The column (of type `DataColumn` has a property `DataType`. If it is `String`, then we can do the replacement.

```
For Each row As DataRow In dtDiffFiles.Rows
    For Each col As DataColumn In dtDiffFiles.Columns
        If col.DataType = GetType(String) AndAlso IsDBNull(row.Item(col)) Then
            row.Item(col) = String.Empty
        End If
    Next
Next
```